# Mysql condition not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, notin

this is my query for getting order total for particular date. Here I can't get proper result when using AND (tos.status!='5' or tos.status!='6'). what is the problem in this?

```
SELECT sum(tot.total) as total 
FROM orders_totals tot, orders tos 
WHERE DATE(tos.`timestamp`) BETWEEN '2013-12-09' AND '2013-12-09' and 
      tot.`order` = tos.id and tot.description='Grand-Total' AND 
     (tos.status!='5' or tos.status!='6')
```

Comment: `(tos.status!='5' or tos.status!='6')`

Is always true. Because is either either not 5 or 6. What should the condition do?

Comment: if I give AND  tos.`status`!='6', it shows correct result

Comment: tell us exactly whats your condition and what you say in your query exactly?

Comment: @Prakash - please add that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(tot.total) as total 
FROM orders_totals tot
INNER JOIN orders tos ON tot.`order` = tos.id
WHERE DATE(tos.`timestamp`) BETWEEN '2013-12-09' AND '2013-12-09' and 
      tot.description='Grand-Total' AND tos.status NOT IN (5, 6)
```